# Read a data from a text file and display data using SDI Application (MFC)?

Tags: c++, mfc

Reading and Writing from the file were easier for me but i am  unable to do it in SDI Application (MFC) ....  i need some guidance to solve this ..........
  here is  constructor

```
    CFileDoc::CFileDoc()
    {
    // TODO: add one-time construction code here
      CFileDialog m_IdFile(true);
      if(m_IdFile.DoModal()==IDOK)
       m_sFileName= m_IdFile.GetFileName();
       fstream outFile;
       string data;

       outFile.open(m_sFileName,ios::in);

    {
              while(outFile.eof()!=true)

            {

                getline(outFile,data);

                m_sName=data;
          }
}
    outFile.close();
```

}

i am doing mistake in this part

```
  m_sName=data;
```

because the Data type of m_sName is CString and the data type of data is string

```
 CString m_sName;

 string data;
```

the error is

```
binary '=' : no operator defined which takes a right-hand operand of type 'class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Relevant: that isn't your only mistake. [**Read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). And you'll probably find [**this important as well.**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a `std::string` to a `CString`, but `CString` has a constructor taking a `const char*` :

```
m_sName = data.c_str();
```

---

Also `while(outFile.eof()!=true)` is wrong (the last read operation will be done *after* `eof` is set !), you should do :

```
while (getline(outFile, data))
{
 ...
```